# Colocar tiempo a la funcion exec en php

Tags: php, python

Hola estoy utilizando un exec para ejecutar un archivo en python, pero tengo un problema el archivo en python se demora en dar respuesta y al devolver en php no me arroja resultado, existe alguna manera de a la funcion exec() pueda colocarle un tiempo de espera ?

```
$salida = array();
exec("python outputPy.py", $salida);
```

Comment: ya coloque un sleep y no funciono, pero es que necesito que php espere que el archivo python  le de respuesta y luego si guarda la respuesta en la variable para poderla utilizar en php, ejecute el archivo python desde la consola y se demora aprox. minuto y medio en responder(es un consumo de un servicio web)

Comment: No es algo definitivo, pero un while puede suspender el programa hasta que la respuesta se haya completado. Por ejemplo, digamos que el programa me genera un archivo al acabar, usando while, yo puedo hacer que el programa espere que ese archivo aparesca, y al aparecer, continue como debe ser.

Comment: El problema es que el programa en python tarda en ejecutarse más del tiempo que tiene PHP como límite, podrías tratar de modificarlo con [set_time_limit()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: pero como utilizaria el set_time_limit()? despues de ejecutar exec()?

Comment: Set_time_limit aumenta el tiempo maximo de ejecucion del script que corras. Lo pones al inicio, y le das un numero por segundos... dale un numero grande para empezar, luego vas cotejando a algo mejor

Comment: Adicionalmente a lo que comenta @Triby, existen limitantes del entorno del servidor para el proceso de solicitud / respuesta. Esto es algo que debes configurar en tu servidor. Para procesos muy costosos se utilizan `workers`. Si tu proceso es bloqueante, te sugiero le des una mirada a estos `workers`. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras hola podrias explicarme un poco mas tu comentario es que no encuentro solucion a mi problema

Comment: @Excorpion lo hice asi pero no resulto, les agradezco otra idea porfa, les explico un poco el proceso, el archivo de python es un servicio web y demora 1min. pero al hacer el llamado desde php lo hace inmediatamente por ende no deja que el archivo en python se termine de consultar, use sleep() set_time_limit y nada